# express 4.x redirect http to https

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, redirect, express

I have the following code :

```
var https        = require('https');
var http         = require('http');
var express      = require('express');
var app          = express();
var router       = express.Router();

app.use('/', router);

//have 'server' listen for https
var server = https.createServer(config.sslCredential, app);
server.listen(config.serverPort);

//listen server on http, and always redirect to https
var httpServer = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.redirect(config.serverDomain+req.url);
});
httpServer.listen(config.httpServerPort);
```

but somehow I can't get the https request to be redirected into https request, how should I do this correctly on node.js with express 4.x ?

Answer (score 40):

Quoting a middleware solution from [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046208/forwarding-http-to-https-in-node-js-express-app-using-ebs-elb-environment/19051185#19051185) (which btw was on express 3.0)

```
app.all('*', ensureSecure); // at top of routing calls

http.createServer(app).listen(80)
https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(443)

function ensureSecure(req, res, next){
  if(req.secure){
    // OK, continue
    return next();
  };
  // handle port numbers if you need non defaults
  // res.redirect('https://' + req.host + req.url); // express 3.x
  res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url); // express 4.x
}
```

Comment: Just as an FYI to anyone using Heroku, ```req.secure``` will not work. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952085/express-js-redirect-to-https-and-send-index-html

Comment: `req.host` (express 3.x) is now `req.hostname` (express 4.x)

Comment: Same goes for Elastic Beanstalk, or any other EC2 instance behind an ELB, where the ELB terminates the HTTPS on behalf of the server.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing this rerouting at the level of something like Nginx?

Comment: Not necessarily. If your server is sitting behind a service like Cloudflare having another layer of nginx in between you and Cloudflare (which uses nginx) is extra complexity you may not need. Depends on your TLS setup with Cloudflare as well - I'm using HTTPS between Cloudflare and my server, so I need to do this redirect in node but it's not a big overhead.

Comment: As of 5/2017 w/ Express v 4.8.0:  `function ensureSecure(req, res, next){
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https'){
    // OK, continue
    return next()
  };

   res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host)
}`

Comment: @PhilAndrews solution of using req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] is valid only when the express server is behind a load balancer which injects the header x-forwarded-proto

Answer (score 3):

You can do redirection to https like this:

```
app.enable('trust proxy')
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.secure ? next() : res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
})
```