# Redirect to HTTPS with Node/Express on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get a site to force HTTPS (redirect from HTTP). We've got HTTPS set up via AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The problem is that, currently, both HTTP and HTTPS can be used.

After reading through a few posts, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952085/express-js-redirect-to-https-and-send-index-html), the code below is what I came up with. Unfortunately this isn't working.

What am I missing?

```
import express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

const app = express();
const buildPath = join(`${__dirname}/../build`);
const enforceHTTPS = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') return next();
  else return res.redirect(301, join(`https://${req.hostname}${req.url}`));
};

app.use(express.static(buildPath));
app.use(enforceHTTPS);
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${buildPath}/index.html`));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000!'));

export default app;
```

Comment: I think you can proxy all https request to http at your node end using aws. Keep node running on http. Otherwise use https server together with express as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I simply had to reorder my app.use statements — calling the redirect *before* serving the static files.

Additionally, in order for this to work on IE/Edge, 'https://' needed to be moved outside of path.join (join removes the second forward slash, and although all other major browsers will handle it properly, IE doesn't like it).

Here's a working example:

```
import express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

const app = express();
const buildPath = join(`${__dirname}/../build`);
const enforceHTTPS = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') return next();
  return res.redirect(301, `https://${join(req.hostname, req.url)}`);
};

app.use(enforceHTTPS);
app.use(express.static(buildPath));
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${buildPath}/index.html`));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000!'));

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have used node.js as a proxy in the past, the way we got unsecure connections to proxy to secure was as follows, amended to match your code:

```
const httpsPort = process.env.HTTPS_PORT;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.secure) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect(301, ['https://', req.hostname, ':', httpsPort, '/', req.url].join('');
}
```

Where `httpsPort` is whatever the port your standard https connections will go through. Where `process.env.HTTPS_PORT` would get the environment variable for the https port (Standard is 443). You could replace this with whatever you want to get the port.

Answer (score -1):

The most obvious issue in your code is that HTTPS is served from port 443.  Besides that looks like outdated code.  Why not use a recent version of Express?  If you look at the example for HTTPS they give here its pretty different from what you wrote: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html search for 'HTTPS'

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to set up a HTTPS server with Express on the application side — it's already set up through AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I'm trying to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

Comment: This will not work on AWS, I have tried it!